# Is there a way to programmatically configure the notification display setting for an ios app?

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I tested it on two iphones : on the first the setting was set to 'none' and on the second it was set to 'banner' (seems weird). I would like to know if there's a way to explicitly code that in the app? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know there's no way to do that.

Comment: It's a bad answer, explain what you have done to realize that it's impossible.